# How to change direction of a vertical Swiper in react-id-swiper (to go from up to down)?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm setting up two vertical sliders next to each other in my react project. One of them has to move upwards and the other one downwards.

I've tried setting `reverseDirection: true` in the settings of one of the sliders, but that does not seem to have any effect. I've also tried `rtl: true`, in hopes that would change the direction but it didn't. Both sliders still move from down to up.

These are the settings to my swiper so far (the one that should move downwards):

```
const SWIPER_PARAMS = {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  slidesPerGroup: 1,
  loop: true,
  direction: 'vertical',
  autoplay: {
    delay: 1
  },
  speed: 5000,
  disableOnInteraction: false,
  reverseDirection: true,
  spaceBetween: 22,
  rtl: true
};
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas how to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did, I just flipped around the slider container and then flipped the slide itself back again:

```
  .slider__container {
     transform: rotate(180deg);

     .swiper-slide {
       transform: rotate(180deg);
     }
  }
```

In case there is anyone else wondering, there isn't a built-in option for this but the rotating works great as well, I now have one slider moving upwards and the other one downwards.